# How to do streaming read of a large XML file in C# 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-3.5, streaming

How can you do a streaming read on a large XML file that contains a xs:sequence just below root element, without loading the whole file into a XDocument instance in memory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Going with a SAX-style element parser and the [XmlTextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.aspx) class created with [XmlReader.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.create.aspx) would be a good idea, yes. Here's a slightly-modified code example from [CodeGuru](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_data/xml/article.php/c4221/):

```
void ParseURL(string strUrl)
{
  try
  {
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(strUrl))
    {
      while (reader.Read())
      {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
          case XmlNodeType.Element:
            var attributes = new Hashtable();
            var strURI = reader.NamespaceURI;
            var strName = reader.Name;
            if (reader.HasAttributes)
            {
              for (int i = 0; i < reader.AttributeCount; i++)
              {
                reader.MoveToAttribute(i);
                attributes.Add(reader.Name,reader.Value);
              }
            }
            StartElement(strURI,strName,strName,attributes);
            break;
            //
            //you can handle other cases here
            //
            //case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
            // Todo
            //case XmlNodeType.Text:
            // Todo
            default:
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      catch (XmlException e)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("error occured: " + e.Message);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A few things I noticed: The catch statement is in the wrong spot (should be after the second-to-last closing curly brace) and there is an extra closing curly brace after the last break statement (it is trying to close the case statement, but you only close the switch statement).  Also, I can't find where the StartElement method comes from, or is that supposed to be a dummy method to be replaced with user code?

Answer (score 7):

I can't add a comment, since I just signed up but the code sample posted by Hirvox and currently selected as the answer has a bug in it. It should not have the `new` statement when using the static `Create` method.

Current:

```
using (var reader = new XmlReader.Create(strUrl))
```

Fixed:

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(strUrl))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible if you want to use object model (i.e. XElement\XDocument) to query XML. Obviously, you can't build XML objects tree without reading enough data. However you can use [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) class.

> The XmlReader class reads XML data
>   from a stream or file. It provides
>   non-cached, forward-only, read-only
>   access to XML data.

Answer (score 0):

Heres is a howto: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301228/en-us Just remember that you should not use XmlTextReader but instead XmlReader in conjunction with XmlReader.Create

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by the mention of the "xs:sequence" - this is a XML Schema element.

Are you trying to open a large XML Schema file? Are you open a large XML file that is based on that schema? Or are you trying to open a large XML file and validate it at the same time?

None of these situations should provide you with a problem using the standard XmlReader (or XmlValidatingReader).

Reading XML with XMLReader: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d83k261(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

That code sample tries to turn XmlReader style code into SAX style code - if you're writing code from scratch I'd just use XmlReader as it was intended - Pull not Push.