# replacing xml tag with html value

Tags: c#, xml, html-parsing, xmldocument, linq-to-xml

I'm working with c# .Net

I have a question,

I'm loading Xml file with `XDocument.xDoc.Load(file)`, but it fails because in my content I also have xml tags:

Example: `<root><abc><deg></abc></root>`

My problem is that the `Load` function treats the `<deg>` as an Xml tag without a matching "`</deg>`"...

My question is, how can i replace the "<" and ">" of the "deg" with the matching "`&lt;`"  "`&gt;`" in the easiest way?

N.B. my file is very big and I have a lot of tags...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is difficult to do with the standard .NET libraries, unless you want to do a lot of difficult parsing.  If there is any rhyme or reason to your non-ended tags, it would help a lot.  For example, is there a known list of tags that are not closed?  If so, the searching and replacing would not be bad.

But, if it is truly open-ended, if **any** tag could be unclosed, then you'll need to use something like [HTML Tidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/).  The .Net wrapper of this is can be [found here](http://markbeaton.com/SoftwareInfo.aspx?ID=81a0ecd0-c41c-48da-8a39-f10c8aa3f931).  With this,solution, the `<deg>` tag would be converted to `<deg/>`.  HTML Tidy wrapper can also fix a few other problems that cause xml to be *mal-formed*.

Once your file contains well-formed xml, then you can load it into xml objects easily.  Then if you have other work to do on the document, you'll at least be able to *see* it as xml.

Comment: nice answer... i have no known list of tags... it can be any tag. i will try to work with the html tidy. after it will be converted to <deg/> (it would be much easier to find them) i will convert it again to &lt;deg&gt; i think that this might work. hope that this library will work for me. (my file is actually in SGML format)

Comment: :). i anyway will, but lets wait for some more answers. i want it to be solved!!! and there are a lot of expert like you that could give me some more good answers.

Answer (score 1):

*Standard regex disclaimer goes here...* - *sometimes* they can come in handy for [HTML cleanup scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473826/parsing-xml-with-ampersand/1474487#1474487).

Give this approach a try:

```
string input = "<root><abc><deg><foo></abc><bar></root>";
string pattern = @"(<(?<tag>\w+)>)(?!.*?</\k<tag>>)";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern,
                         match => HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(match.Value));
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(result);
Console.WriteLine(document.ToString());
```

Of course be mindful of the file size and that other suggestions maybe more suitable if performance is important for the overall process.

**EDIT:** the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is an alternate option for sanitizing any malformed content. If you know the content you could go in there and replace them with valid closing tags.

Comment: hi! thank for the answer... your sample did worked for me. but it didn't work with my file.although i think that your answer is very close, and helping alot. my file is in SGML format. when i try to use your example i get "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1." (thats why i didn't use the LoadXml from the beginning...). perhaps a can some how convert the SGML to Xml and then, with your solution, it would solve my problem.

Comment: @Jack did you try using just `Load(filename)` ? Are you loading a string or a file? Your original code showed a filename, whereas I was using a string, so just to be sure we're all on the same page. Also, what does the beginning of your SGML file look like? Perhaps you could update your question with a small sample of the SGML file.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get at that section before you load it into the `XmlDocument` then you could use the [`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode.aspx) method to entity-escape the content for you.

The other thing you might want to consider is wrapping your XML-looking content as [`CDATA`](http://www.w3schools.com/xmL/xml_cdata.asp), which will effectively hide this content from the parser.

Comment: hi! HttpUtility.HtmlEncode didn't do anything with the file. about CDADA my problem is how to easely find the problematic tag...

Answer (score 0):

If this file is really big then you should use XmlReader instead of XmlDocument and there is no "not closed tags" issue.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28VS.80%29.aspx

Example:
[How to do streaming read of a large XML file in C# 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481/how-to-do-streaming-read-of-a-large-xml-file-in-c-3-5)

Comment: the file is actually in SGML format.
(that why i didn't use xDoc.LoadXml)
how can changing from XmlDocument to XmlReader help me?

Comment: thanks! i will try to check it tomorrow morning and let you know :)
i'm struggling with it for quite some time. :)

Comment: So, if you read it using an xmlReader, it will recognizes unclosed tags, and then you convert it to xmlDocument or XDocument or whatever, you'll have closed tags?