# XDocument.Load ( XmlReader) has horrible performance; 2 MB XML from Web-Service needs 4 sec from Stream to parse

Tags: c#, xml, performance, web-services, stream

I am calling a webservice, which returns a xml with about 2MB.

Everything quite standard. The Problem is the creation of a XDocument.

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load( XMLReader Object); // takes 4 sec!!!
```

I am creating xdoc because I use LINQ to XML to read the XML.

```
Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(MyUri);
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
req.Method = "POST";

req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.ContentLength = Poststring.Length;

StreamWriter swriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
swriter.Write(Poststring);
swriter.Close();

s.Start();
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
XmlReader MyXmlReader = null;

XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ProhibitDtd = false;
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.None;
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;

Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
s.Stop(); 
Debug.WriteLine("stream= response.GetResponseStream(): " + s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
s.Reset();

MyXmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings);

Debug.WriteLine("Before XDocument.Load(MyXmlReader): " + s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
s.Start();
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(MyXmlReader);
s.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine("Duration: " + s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

The PC is 2 years old, 4 GB RAM. The PC is ok. I tested it on 2 other PCs and Laptop and got same results. My way of the creation of XDocument xdoc takes just to long, but why?

I tested

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(String with path to the same xmlFile on my pc);
```

and it took like 20 Milliseconds.

EDIT:
here some timings:

```
stream= response.GetResponseStream(): 5276 Milliseconds
```

I guess this is the time from Server to my pc

Duration: 4855

time needed for: `XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(MyXmlReader);`

Maybe a problem because it is Stream beeing "converted" into XDocument xdoc object?

edit2: I just tested

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

//responsetime from server to my pc: 6000 ms
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream(); 
stream.CopyTo(ms); //this operation takes 4000 ms!!!
ms.Position = 0;
XDocument x4 = XDocument.Load(ms);// this takes 13 ms!!!
```

The conversion of the data in the stream object to some useful data(like string or ms) take that long, but why?

Am I right, that all data from Web-service are 100% sent and have arrived and only then the next line of code is beeing performed? or is stream.copyTo(ms) operating on a stream that is open and still receiving data?

Comment: Have you measured the performance over the wire? If I were to try and download 2MB from a remote host over my DSL connection at home, I'd not expect it to come back in less than about 15 seconds.

Comment: *Your own test* establishes that the problem is very much *not* 'the creation of a XDocument'...

Comment: I do not think so. Because i am measuruing 1) time from webServer to me and 2) XDocument.Load(XmlReader). I reset also the time within Stopwatch.

Comment: Have a look at this question, it may help you [How to do Streaming read of a large XML file in C# 3.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481/how-to-do-streaming-read-of-a-large-xml-file-in-c-sharp-3-5), [In C# What is the best way to parse Large XML (Size of 1GB)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468948/in-c-sharp-what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-large-xml-size-of-1gb) and [What is the best way to parse (big) XML in C# Code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676274/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-big-xml-in-c-sharp-code)

Comment: thx for the links, but with my 2 MB i think the prblem is with the data within the streamobject. Somehow it takes very long to convert it to anything useful. If i use stream.CopyTo(memorystream), every operation on memorystream is like 100x faster than operation on stream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the line:

```
MyXmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings);
```

You are reading from a `Stream`, which is essentially a **pipe**, not a **bucket**; the stream does not yet have all that data. I'm guessing that 2MB is taking about 4 seconds to arrive down the wire.

If that is too long, make sure you have enabled gzip/deflate on the http connection. As oberfreak notes, there are other data formats that are more suited to large documents (xml can become unwieldy at large sizes, although it will generally work).

Comment: hmmm i was already starting to implement gzip/deflate but the web-service guys would have to implement that too. How do i make sure, that all data is on my pc, before i start with XDocument xdoc= XDocument.Load();? So that i can really say, how long does XDocument.Load(); take?

Comment: @Gero most web servers can support gzip/deflate simply by enabling it; re your question... you could copy it to a MemoryStream? `var ms = new MemoryStream(); stream.CopyTo(ms); ms.Position = 0;` - HOWEVER!!! it is much more efficient to read from the stream without this extra buffer, so only do this to satisfy yourself on where the time is going.

Comment: thx for your advice. i used stream.CopyTo(ms) **3850ms** then i used XDocument x4 = XDocument.Load(ms); **13ms**. Looks like the problem is the data within the stream object The conversion of that stream data to something useful takes 4 sec?? the data from webserver to me need about 6 sec.

Comment: @Gero there is no "conversion of that stream" - this stream is simply gathering data over the network, the same as downloading a file. It takes a few seconds.

Comment: @Gero the only time it is being interpreted as anything is the 13ms

Comment: i am not quite sure. I know now that  XDocument.Load() is not the problem, but rather getting the data out of the stream.

Comment: @Gero no, the problem is "getting the data over the wire", which simply means you are constrained by bandwidth. Welcome to the club; we all are. If you want it to be faster, there are 3 choices; a: speed up delivery (pay for a fatter pipe, and ensure the server will supply data at that rate), b: compress it on the wire, or c: send less data (I believe someone mentioned protobuf, which is designed to be less verbose than XML)